# Using a WindowsXP VBScript to automate Internet Explorer, how can I 'click ok' when a dialog box appears?

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, windows-xp

My Windows VBScript opens an InternetExplorer.Application object, and runs through some navigation.  At one point the page I'm working with displays a dialog box in which I must click "OK" or "Cancel."  Is there a way to tell the VBScript to click "OK" when the dialog box pops up?

Comment: For now I have added a workaround that will render IE visible just for the confirm box to display, then go back to being invisible.  Luckily it takes very little time for this script to run, so it isn't a hassle to wait 2 seconds for the popup.  Any ideas on other workarounds are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

VBScript isn't very good at dealing with GUI functions, at least, it is not even remotely close to something like AutoIT; anyway, that said there is a sendkeys function in VBScript, but the problem is that you can't do an "on event" type of call, you basically have to use a timer, so it really isn't a good solution, but as far as I know it's all you've got, at least natively to VBS.

So maybe you could kick off your IE object, then throw in a wait timer and then sendkeys.  WAY hokey... but it *could* work.

[Here's the MSDN article on sendkeys with examples.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to close a dialog box, this may help you:

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 

Do 
    bResult = oShell.AppActivate("Title of the dialog box") 
    If bResult = True Then 
        oShell.SendKeys "{Enter}" 
        ' or "%K" for Alt+k, for OK and "%N" (Alt+N) for Cancel
        Exit Do 
    End If 
    WScript.Sleep 500 
Loop
```

Comment: @java_enthu: yes it does. `oShell.AppActivate("Title of the dialog box")` activates it, then sends the keys to close it. You may use `Add comment` to comment this answer instead of answering the question.